# R dataframe split based on multiple factor values (multiple months)

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm working with the example data `airquality` and I want to split the dataframe into where month is between 5-10 and where the month are the other values.

What I have:

```
aq <- na.omit(airquality)
aq$MonthF <- factor(aq$Month)  # Make the month a factor
```

What I tried (split):

```
aq_s <- split(aq, aq$MonthF %in% c(5:10))
aq_n <- split(aq, aq$MonthF %in% c(1:4, 11:12))
```

and I tried (subset):

```
aq_s <- subset(aq, MonthF %in% c(5:10))
aq_n <- subset(aq, MonthF %in% c(1:4, 11:12))
```

Result:

```
> head(aq_n)
data frame with 0 columns and 6 rows
```

I still couldn't figure it out after looking at other stackoverflow questions. How do I properly split this dataframe into 2 groups?

Comment: Please check the `aq`, You don't have levels 1:4 and 11:12  `unique(aq$Month)#
[1] 5 6 7 8 9`

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot. I was checking it with head(aq).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @akrun, I didn't properly check the data:

```
unique(aq$Month)  # [1] 5 6 7 8 9
```

So to still answer this question, but say I want to split the data based on month 5, 7-9, this would work:

```
aq_s <- subset(aq, MonthF %in% c(5, 7:9))
aq_n <- subset(aq, MonthF %in% c(6))

unique(aq_s$MonthF)
# [1] 5 7 8 9
# Levels: 5 6 7 8 9

unique(aq_n$MonthF)
# [1] 6
# Levels: 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Try executing `unique(aq$Month)`. You'll see the only months in the dataset are May-September.

Additionally, here's a solution using dplyr:
`aq_s <- aq %>% filter( MonthF %in% c(5:10) )`
`aq_n <- aq %>% filter( MonthF %in% c(1:4, 11:12) )`

Again, `aq_n` *should* be empty because there are no matching records in the dataframe.